# Failed to assign to property in Creating Custom Component (Winrt)?

Tags: properties, user-controls, windows-runtime, custom-controls

I am trying to make my custom component but need help.

```
    private string _passwordText;
    public string PasswordText
    {
        get
        {
            _passwordText = passwordB.Password;
            return _passwordText;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty<string>(ref _passwordText, value, "PasswordText");
            passwordB.Password = _passwordText;
            passwordB_PasswordChanged(passwordB, null);
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(storage, value)) return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

An exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in AkbankStoreApp.exe but was not handled in user code

WinRT information: Failed to assign to property 'Windows8.StoreApp.Common.CustomControls.WatermarkPasswordTextBox.PasswordText'. [Line: 51 Position: 26]

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an OnApplyTemplate override? Is that where passwordB comes from? If so you might need to check if passwordB is not null before you assign a value to its property. Check [this](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/WatermarkPasswordBox/WatermarkPasswordBox.cs) for reference.

Comment: Hi Filip, thanks for your interest. I have not OnApplyTemplate but I am checking is passwordB null. I am trying noe OnApplyTemplate